# При попытке парсинга сайта с использованием cUrl выдаёт "setting cookie..."

Tags: php, парсер, curl, php-curl

Нужно спарсить данные с этого сайта https://bankrot.fedresurs.ru/ выдаёт сообщение "setting cookie..." выглядит так http://prntscr.com/q9gmwd использую следующий код:

```
$url = "https://bankrot.fedresurs.ru";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
$content = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($content);
curl_close($ch);
```

Изначально выдавало ошибку 403 Forbiden я добавил отправление заголовка, чтобы сайт воспринимал как запрос от реального человека, после этого и появилось "setting cookie..." пробовал установить куки никакого эффекта это не даёт. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте функцию php: [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php)

Пример из документации:

```html
<?php
  $homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
  echo $homepage;
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо, file_get_contents пробовал не помогает

Answer (score 0):

Возможно сервер использует защиту от ботов с помощью cookie:

- проверить наличие некой "магической" cookie
- если cookie отсутствует

  - установить cookie
  - послать редирект на эту же страничку
- если cookie присутствует - отдать страничку

Если сайт действительно заморочился с защитой от ботов, проще будет взять selenium или puppeteer/chrome-php

Comment: Спасибо. Как обойти эту защиту? Надо устанавливать куки при помощи cUrl? Какое название ей указывать?

Comment: @Антон см CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE и CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php . Но, опять же, для crawling-задач я обычно использую puppeteer.js - возможностей больше, гемороя меньше